# Query custom post type that has a serialized relational advanced custom field value

Tags: custom-post-types, php, wp-query, custom-field

I have a custom post type "**issues**".

I am using Advanced Custom Fields to add a relational field called "**articles_from_this_issue**" where the admin can select multiple articles.

I have an author template where I display all of the authors posts (articles).

I need to query the "**issues**" custom post type and check to see if each article is one of the selected "**articles_from_this_issue**"

here is what I have tried so far but nothing seems to work.

```
$issues_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'issues', 
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key' => 'articles_from_this_issue',
            'value' => serialize( intval(get_the_ID()) ),
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ),
    ));

$the_issues_query = new WP_Query( $issues_args );
```

I have also tried this:

```
$issues_args = array(
'post_type' => 'issues', 
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key' => 'articles_from_this_issue',
        'compare' => 'LIKE',
        'value' => get_the_ID(),
    ),
));
```

Here is what the database shows in the "wp_postmeta" table:

```
meta_id: 27533
post_id: 733
meta_key: articles_from_this_issue
meta_value: a:2:{i:0;s:4:"3187";i:1;s:4:"3230";}
```

[image]

Any and all help is much appreciated!

Comment: I guess using `'compare' => 'LIKE'` with `'value' => '"' . get_the_ID() . '"'` would work. But why didn't you add "issues" as a custom taxonomy instead? That way, you'd just use a taxonomy query (`tax_query`) when searching for the articles that are in a specific term in the "issues" taxonomy.

Comment: @SallyCJ I already tried 'LIKE' with 'value' => '"' . get_the_ID() . '"' and it still does not work. Issues need to be a custom post type for multiple reasons.

Comment: So you are making the query in each post loop on the author archive page? Are you sure you want to use `get_the_ID()` and that it has the correct value like the `3187` in the question?

Comment: @SallyCJ yes I did check and get_the_ID() does pull in 3187

Comment: In that case, then I could only ask you to try again what I suggested in my first comment and then do `var_dump( $the_issues_query->request );` after you do `new WP_Query()`. And then just check if the SQL query is good and you could also try running it in phpMyAdmin and then see if it returns any results.

Comment: `SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS DISTINCT wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id ) LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id WHERE 1=1 AND ( ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'articles_from_this_issue' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value LIKE '{57f09bc502b22178f2f2d57f927e718fe8406b68e6cb3a95eb4d05d514d93ec8}\"3187\"{57f09bc502b22178f2f2d57f927e718fe8406b68e6cb3a95eb4d05d514d93ec8}' ) ) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'issues' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish') GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.menu_order, wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10`

Comment: @SallyCJ see comment above ^^

Comment: There's something wrong in the query - it has two joins on the posts meta table (`INNER JOIN wp_postmeta` and `LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta`) and yet, the second join should have used a unique table alias. Can you show the full query args (`$issues_args` array) you used? But if the one in question is what you actually used, then there's a plugin or custom code which is filtering the query (args), but not done correctly and consequently causing the issue.

Comment: @SallyCJ Is good to note that this is inside a while loop?

Comment: What do you mean by that? Are you saying that because it's inside the while loop, then the other table join is not using a unique alias?

Comment: That is correct. It’s inside the whole loop

Comment: No, that is not going to happen. Otherwise, it would've been a major issue in WordPress because what I was saying is that the SQL query you shared has an **error**. So just try deactivating all plugins (except maybe, ACF and if any, the plugin you used to register your post type) and see if the issue persists.

Comment: PS: Note that those `{57f09bc502b22178f2f2d57f927e718fe8406b68e6cb3a95eb4d05d514d93ec8}` are not the error. Instead, they're called placeholder (`%`) escape strings and will be changed back to `%` when `WP_Query` sends the query to MySQL. So try replacing those with `%` and then run the query in phpMyAdmin (or a similar tool), and you'd notice the error for yourself. Also, if or once you've resolved the issue, you should write an answer and explain what you did - it might help someone else :)

Comment: Will do. I have to go out of town but will resolve this when I get back and will post an answer. Thank you for your help